# Android SocialAuth Facebook message not post

Tags: android, facebook

I m using socialauth android sdk,
After Facebook log in it is saying, **This does not let the app post to Facebook**

why i m getting this message, i have put App Id and App Secrete in socialauth oauth_consumer.properties file,